# Blender and Unity Texture Arrays - How to set w value in Blenders UV's

Tags: uv, unity

Maybe I'm missing something obvious but so far I couldn't find a lot about it. In Unity you can use the feature of Texture Arrays by just picking the w value of your texcoords (UV's) in a shader, to pick a different texture for shading. Basically the w represents the texture index in the array.

How do you set the w value for UV's in Blender?

I only managed to find a workaround by setting vertex colors, which seems to be an unnecessary extra step. Or by going with UDIM's which I think is a bit of an overshoot, and also Unity doesn't support it entirely as far as I know.

Comment: I think LabCat's answer is good (and I upvoted on that basis) but you might find it easier to use an extra UV layer rather than vertex color.  In that case, you would simply use one dimension of that UV layer as your w.  This has the advantage of *feeling* more appropriate, and you won't get stung if you run into some situation where, say, vertex color is being treated as sRGB data rather than as non-color, spatial data.

Comment: Good point. I just tried vertex colors just for comparison and the different color spaces being applied already create headaches haha... I just have to first make sure that the second UV layer isn't used for something special in Unity, because I vaguely remember reading something about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such feature in Blender (I.e. nothing quite like how you’ve described a W value or a texture array), but there are other ways to do the same thing. One shader can incorporate different textures, and mix between them for a shader’s base color. Vertex colors’ channels can be used as a factor for the mixing, and with some math notes, one channel could select between multiple textures.

As for compatibility with Unity, I’m afraid you might have to do some extra post-transporting work. It’s features like this that typically need human translation between 3-D programs. While UV maps are thankfully a pretty old/universal standard, most ways of handling shaders are often very unique to the software.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the clarification. I guess I'll have to do a little workaround with vertex colors then. Just a bit surprised that you have no way to edit the 3rd coordinate, since it seems to be quite simple to implement.